# spark worker number of core performance

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, cpu-cores

I'm wondering about the impact of number of cores of a spark worker and streaming performance.
Context is spark standalone configuration with 2 master and 6 spark-worker.
Applications are kafka spark streaming.
kafka 0.8.2.1 and spark 1.5.1

Some fellows modified the number of core from 9 to 12 and curiously, one kafka streaming application passed from 200 msg/s to 120 msg/s.
Physically, each spark worker node is 16Gb and 6 processor.

I verified that there is no memory swap or cpu overhead on spark workers node.

Any idea ?

Comment: Which number of core? You say from 9 to 12, but then you speak about 6 processor, can you explain clearly the differences? In addition, might there be some differences in the input provided in kafka that could account for the diff?

Comment: Hi, I think each spark worker server has 6 physical processors. From 9 to 12 is the configuration of each worker. I know documentation says it should be number of processors minus 1. I try to understand how spark manages its cores

Comment: Finally, the approach is to add CPU to each spark worker and performance are coming back.